# React Native StackNavigator default props for screens

Tags: react-native, redux, reducers, stack-navigator

I am using 2 seperate StackNavigators in my application and render one them in an if condition structure. 
For Example :

```
if(this.props.authToken)//authToken is a state object setting in one of my reducers
return <AppNavigator />
else
return <AuthNavigator />
```

See i will use that authToken object almost in every screen of AppNavigator.

One way i am using currently is that getting that on my "mapStateToProps" function in every screens export statement.

```
class SomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
           <View><Text>Some UI {this.props.authToken.userName} </Text></View>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {

//This line that i have to write in every screen
       authToken: state.app.authToken
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {...}
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SomeScreen);
```

But it i didn't like that. So if there is an object that i might use in most of my navigator screens I desire that passing it from my root component to rendering navigator component like :

```
 if(this.props.authToken)//authToken is a state object setting in one of my reducers
    return <AppNavigator authToken={this.props.authToken} someOtherCommonProp={{....}}/>
    else
    return <AuthNavigator />
```

So my question is that what would be the best practise for that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think if `authToken` will not vary in time or get update it by external way you don´t have to use it in redux state, so in my opinion your solution looks good. Please let me know.